# Geometric progression, two equations problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, systems-of-equations, geometric-progressions

We have two equations:
$$1. \ a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 21$$

$$2. \ a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 = 189$$

Answer should by $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$.
How the title says, these 3 elements are part of geometric progression.

I have no idea how to solve that problem. Any description on how to solve it mathematically, not just bruteforce it by guessing will be great. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the terms are $m, mr, mr^2$.

$(2)\div(1):$

$$\begin{align}
9&=\frac{m^2(1+r^2+r^4)}{m(1+r+r^2)}\\
&=\frac{m(1-r+r^2)(1+r+r^2)}{1+r+r^2}\\
&=m(1-r+r^2)&&\text{as }1+r+r^2\neq0\end{align}$$
and the solution for which is 
$$m=3, r=2$$
i.e. the three numbers are $3,6,12$.

Answer (score 0):

It tells you that these elements are part of a geometric progression, which means that you obtain each successive term after the first by multiplying by a fixed constant $k$, so that $a_2 = ka_1$ and $a_3 = k^2a_1$. This gives us a system of two equations in two variables:

$$a_1 + ka_1 + k^2a_1 = 21$$
$$a_1^2+k^2a_1^2+k^4a_1^2=189$$

Factoring out $a_1$ and $a_1^2$:

$$a_1(1+k+k^2)=21$$
$$a_1^2(1+k^2+k^4)=189$$

I want to combine these to get one equation in terms of $k$, so I will isolate the $a_1$, then substitute.

$$a_1=\frac{(1+k+k^2)}{21}$$
$$a_1^2=\frac{(1+k^2+k^4)}{189}$$
Squaring both sides in the first equation:

$$a_1^2=\frac{(1+k+k^2)}{21^2}$$

Substituting for $a_1^2$:

$$\frac{(1+k+k^2)^2}{21^2}=\frac{(1+k^2+k^4)}{189}$$

Cross multiply and combine like terms to get a polynomial in $k$:

$$0=4k^4-6k^3-2k^2-6k+4$$
$$0=2k^4-3k^3-k^2-3k+2$$

This can be factored using synthetic division and the rational roots theorem, and we find $k=2$, and can then solve for $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$. I found $a_1=3$, $a_2=6$, $a_3=12$.

Comment: I know this, but I wasn't able to get anywhere from this..

Comment: After substituting out the $a_2$ and $a_3$, we are left with a system of two equations in two variables. I'll write the process I used to solve for $k$ in the original answer, because it's easier to format.